# Understand python hdf5storage functions

Tags: python, matlab, hdf5, hdf5storage

Is there anyone explain exact difference between `hdf5storage.write()` and `hdf5storage.writes()` functions. I've read documents but I did not understand it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained in the [`hdf5storage` docs](https://pythonhosted.org/hdf5storage/introduction.html). Quoting:

- The main functions in this module are `write()` and `read()` which
  write **a single Python variable** to an HDF5 file (or reads and
  returns the read data).
- Version 0.1.10 added added two new functions: `writes()` and
  `reads()`.
- They write and read **more than one Python variable** at once, although
  they can still work with a single variable.
- Calling `write()` opens and closes the HDF5 file. As a result,
  calling `write()` multiple times for multiple variables incurs a
  performance penalty. This is most noticeable with large HDF5 files.
- In addition, `savemat()` and `loadmat()` (to work with MATLAB data)
  now use `writes()` and `reads()` for improved performance.

Complete documentation is here for [`write()`](https://pythonhosted.org/hdf5storage/hdf5storage.html#write) and [`writes()`](https://pythonhosted.org/hdf5storage/hdf5storage.html#writes).

For a Python variable named 'a', a simple `write()` call looks like:

```
hdf5storage.write(a, path='/a', filename='data.h5')
```

The `writes()` call uses a dictionary where keys are HDF5 paths and values are data to write to the file. For a dictionary name `mdict`, the call looks like this:

```
hdf5storage.writes(mdict, filename='data.h5')
```

Examples of each below for 3 arrays:

```
arr1 = np.arange(10)
arr2 = np.arange(10,20).reshape(5,2)
arr3 = np.arange(20,30).reshape(2,5)
hdf5storage.write(arr1, path='/arr1', filename='write_data.h5')
hdf5storage.write(arr2, path='/arr2', filename='write_data.h5')
hdf5storage.write(arr3, path='/arr3', filename='write_data.h5')

mdict = {'/arr1':arr1, '/arr2':arr2, '/arr3':arr3}
hdf5storage.writes(mdict, filename='writes_data.h5')
```

The resulting files should be the same.